# Can't change axes in R for density plots when using mixtools

Tags: r, plot

This should be easy to fix, I genuinely don't know what is wrong.

Suppose I wanted to perform the EM algorithm for the Old Faithful data in R and plot the results:

```
install.packages('mixtools')
library('mixtools')

test<-normalmixEM(faithful$waiting, k=2)
plot(test, which=2, xlim= c(30, 100))
lines(density(faithful$waiting), lty=2, lwd=2)
```

This works.
But if I wanted to change the x-label or y-axis I get an error message:

```
plot(test, which=2, xlim= c(30, 100), xlab="", ylim= c(0, 0.06))
lines(density(faithful$waiting), lty=2, lwd=2)
```

The message is:

> argument 4 matches multiple formal arguments

Can someone please help me out? What am I doing wrong? I'm really puzzled.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `xlab2` instead of `xlab`. See `?plot.mixEM`.

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Comment: I did not know that the problem was that I was using mixtools, but I edited the title!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you need to follow this form:

```
 plot(x, whichplots = 1, 
     loglik = 1 %in% whichplots,
     density = 2 %in% whichplots,
     xlab1="Iteration", ylab1="Log-Likelihood",
     main1="Observed Data Log-Likelihood", col1=1, lwd1=2,
     xlab2=NULL, ylab2=NULL, main2=NULL, col2=NULL, 
     lwd2=2, alpha = 0.05, marginal = FALSE, ...)
```

you'll need to use `xlab2 = ...`

Answer (score 0):

`plot()` is a generic function that actually calls a more specific function (called a "method") depending on what you are trying to plot (see [this](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html) chapter from Hadley Wickham's *Advanced R* book for details).  In this case, you are feeding-in an object of class "mixEM" to `plot()`.  You can see this by running, e.g.:

```
class(test)
```

The generic function `plot()` is calling the method `plot.mixEM()` because you are feeding in an object of type "mixEM". To see which parameters of `plot.mixEM()` you can control, check out that function's help page

```
?plot.mixEM
```

The helpfile makes it clear that you need `xlab2` as an argument instead of `xlab`.  However, I don't immediately see how to change `ylim`, so you should view the source code for `plot.mixEM` to see if there's a way to adjust it other components of the graph:

```
getAnywhere(plot.mixEM)
```

Comment: `xlab1` is to be passed to the loglikelihood plot. This is density plot, it should be `xlab2`

Comment: Thanks for the catch see-king.  I've edited my answer.